# Type mismatch with iterator of traits as function argument

Tags: rust, iterator, type-conversion, traits

I have a function that accepts a trait as argument wrapped in a `Box`

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;

fn push(e: Box<dyn Display>) {}

push(Box::new(0));
```

Now I'd like to create another function that accepts an iterator where each Item is of the same type

```rust
fn push_batch<I>(batch: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = Box<dyn Display>>,
{
}

push_batch((0..10).map(|i| Box::new(i)));
```

But doing so results in the following error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<[closure@src/main.rs:13:28: 13:43] as FnOnce<({integer},)>>::Output == Box<(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)>`
  --> src/main.rs:13:5
   |
5  | fn push_batch<I>(batch: I)
   |    ---------- required by a bound in this
6  | where
7  |     I: IntoIterator<Item = Box<dyn Display>>,
   |                     ----------------------- required by this bound in `push_batch`
...
13 |     push_batch((0..10).map(|i| Box::new(i)));
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^ expected integer, found trait object `dyn std::fmt::Display`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Box<{integer}>`
              found struct `Box<(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Iterator` for `Map<std::ops::Range<{integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:13:28: 13:43]>`
```

Why does the first example compile while the second doesn't? And how can I create an iterator of boxed traits to pass to the `push_batch` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust does not automatically cast `Box<T>` to `Box<dyn Trait>`, you must do it explicitly:

```rust
push_batch((0..10).map(|i| Box::new(i) as Box<dyn Display>));
```

Comment: What happens in the first case with `push(Box::new(0));`?

Comment: Rust infers the type to be `Box<dyn Display>`, however the type inference starts to fail for more complicated expressions, especially involving trait bounds.

Comment: You can also use `Box::new(i) as _`. In this case Rust is smart enough to infer the desired type, it just wants you to spell out the intent.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if this is on purpose (having to manually specify the intent/cast) in the iterator case, while not having to do so in the first case. And if this is intentional or actually just a limitation of the compiler.